# Command for wpa_cli to scan a particular network SSID

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

Is there a command supported by `wpa_cli` to make `wpa_supplicant` scan and yield the results of my desired network using the SSID instead of making supplicant scan all the nearby networks?

Comment: The driver+hardware will always scan for all networks when doing a scan, and that won't take more effort than scanning for a particular SSID (if this was possible). The most you can do is to filter the output in one way or other.

Answer (score 3):

The command should be:

```
wpa_cli scan
wpa_cli scan_results | grep "fixed SSID"
```

It will display only the information about the `fixed SSID`.